# Why is my Mongoose schema missing one of its fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema:

```
var RegionSchema = new Schema({
  "metadata": {
    "type": String,
    "name": String,
    "children": [{
      "name": String,
      "type": String
    }],
    "parent": Schema.ObjectId
  },

  "data": [DataContainer]
});
```

This is a unit test I am writing, in which I store an instance of this object with some null values:

```
describe('Region with no data', function() {
  it('Should save without error', function(done) {
    var emptyRegion = new Region({
      "metadata": {
        "type": "City",
        "name": "San Diego",
        "children": [],
        "parent": null
      },

      "data": []
    });

    emptyRegion.save(function(err, saved) {
      console.log(saved)
      if (err) throw err;
      if (saved.metadata.name === "San Diego")
        done();
    })
  });
});
```

However, when I try to print out what is saved, I get this:

```
{ __v: 0, _id: 551cd261cc55c5ff48c8150b, data: [] }
```

Why is my `metadata` object not saving? Even before the `save` call, `emptyRegion` looks just like that. Am I not defining my `metadata` correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annoying culprit is the `type` field within the metadata subdocument. Mongoose interprets that as meaning that metadata is of type `String` and has a bunch of irrelevant properties. Change your schema definition to the following and it should work:

```
var RegionSchema = new Schema({
  "metadata": {
    "type": {"type": String},
    "name": String,
    "children": [{
      "name": String,
      "type": {"type": String}
    }],
    "parent": Schema.ObjectId
  },

  "data": [DataContainer]
});
```

Alternatively, use a different name for your `type` fields.

Comment: Boy, that was a funny one. I have spent over an hour stuck on this one. You have made me really happy!